# Recyclerview not refreshing after returning to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i have favorites fragment with recyclerview , the data is showing well
but when i click on a reyclerview item and remove it from favorites when pressing back to the favorites fragment is still showing in the recylerview , i know that the probleme is recyclerview is not refrishing because when i restart the app the item is removed , i tried notifydatasetchanged but its not working
here is oncreateview and onresume of the favorites fragment

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites, container, false);

    activity=getActivity();

    tinydb = new TinyDB(activity);

    liststorieshits=(RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lsv_cat_item_fav);
    liststorieshits.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));





    rippleView = ((RippleView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rect_fav));
    liststorieshits.setHasFixedSize(true);
    liststorieshits.addItemDecoration(new VerticalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity()).build());
    mAdapter=new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(),itemsList);

    liststorieshits.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progress.setTitle("Loading");
    progress.setMessage("Wait while loading Stories");
    progress.show();

    RestAdapter restAdapter=new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(getString(R.string.categories_feed)).build();
    final CategoriesApiInterface categoriesApiInterface=restAdapter.create(CategoriesApiInterface.class);



    idlist2=tinydb.getListInt("strid");
    int ab=0;
    for(int i=0;i<idlist2.size();i++){
        ab=idlist2.get(i);
        categoriesApiInterface.getStreams3(ab, new Callback<List<Stories>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Stories> stories, Response response) {

                progress.dismiss();
                if (stories == null || stories.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }

                for (Stories stories1 : stories) {
                    itemsList.add(stories1);


                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e("Stories", "krb :" + itemsList.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                progress.dismiss();

                Log.e("Stories", "Retrofit error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
    return rootView;

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Do you have two activities? And when you click in back button goes back to the activity with favorite fragment?

Comment: Is this your child fragment ? I mean do you created this fragment inside another fragment like tab view ?

Comment: no its not a child fragment , yes @Luiz ihave two activities when i delete an item in the 2nd activity and press back back to the fragment the item still on the recyclerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this way to update your RecycleView:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    itemsList.clear();
    idlist2=tinydb.getListInt("strid");
    int ab=0;
    for(int i=0;i<idlist2.size();i++){
        ab=idlist2.get(i);
        categoriesApiInterface.getStreams3(ab, new Callback<List<Stories>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Stories> stories, Response response) {

                progress.dismiss();
                if (stories == null || stories.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }

                for (Stories stories1 : stories) {
                    itemsList.add(stories1);


                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e("Stories", "krb :" + itemsList.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                progress.dismiss();

                Log.e("Stories", "Retrofit error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    mAdapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(),itemsList);
    liststorieshits.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

**ADDED**

You may make `update()` for updating data in separate function, like this:

```
private void update() {
        itemsList.clear();
        idlist2=tinydb.getListInt("strid");
        int ab=0;
        for(int i=0;i<idlist2.size();i++){
            ab=idlist2.get(i);
            categoriesApiInterface.getStreams3(ab, new Callback<List<Stories>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<Stories> stories, Response response) {

                progress.dismiss();
                if (stories == null || stories.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }

                for (Stories stories1 : stories) {
                    itemsList.add(stories1);


                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e("Stories", "krb :" + itemsList.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                progress.dismiss();

                Log.e("Stories", "Retrofit error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    mAdapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(),itemsList);
    liststorieshits.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

And use it:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        update();
    }
```

Comment: thank u for your answer , but it did not update , still the same probleme , should i remove cache or something ?

Comment: if the method `onResume()` is called? And how do you remove items from `itemsList`?

Comment: i remove it in the 2nd activity using sharedpreference tinydb

Comment: so, you need update `itemsList`, and then `RecycleView` will be updated. See my updated post.

Comment: that actually did the trick , but on fragment start is calling the onresume() method so on the fragment start the items is doubling on the reyclerview , but when return to the fragment from another activity the reyclerview is refreshed and the items are ok , so i think on fragment start its calling onstart + onresume thats why the items are twice big

Comment: thank you @walkmn i removed that code from oncreate and now its updating well , thank you you are a life saver

Comment: I would not recommend to reinstantiate `mAdapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(),itemsList);` every time calling `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    binding.mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?